# Using PowerShell, can I find when a user account was created?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, event-log

It's a simple question. I know the information is there somewhere. I've been hammering away with Powershell for 3 days and getting close. I'm runnin' out of time to be honest.

Here's the situation. Person goes in and creates an account on a local machine (windows 7). How do I find when the account was created. I understand looking NTUSER.DATE dates in the profile, but that doesn't quite work. I get information all spread out in the csv and no easy way to get it readable.

```
Get-Item  -force "C:\Users\*\ntuser.dat" |
 Where {((Get-Date)-$_.lastwritetime).days } | 
 Out-File c:\profiles.csv
```

I can see the information in the security log, and I can pull all 4720 events. However, that too is inconsistent, especially if some rascal (like me) cleared out the event log a couple of months ago.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 4720 } |
 EXPORT-CSV C:\NewStaff.csv
```

But that doesn't really get me what I need either. All I need is the username and the date the account was created. I know it's not that simple (although it should be LOL). It's a one time job and I suck at Powershell (although, I've learned a lot over the past couple of days).

Anyway, if someone wouldn't mind throwing me a bone, I'd appreciate it.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed very close. All you need now is formatting. Example:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName "Security" | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 4720 } `
    | Select-Object -Property `
        @{Label="LogonName";Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}}, `
        @{Label="CreationTime";Expression={$_.TimeGenerated}} `
    | Export-Csv C:\NewStaff.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @Alex...thanks for the formatting. I couldn't get it down before and gave up on it. Now, I see where I was wrong. This doesn't help right now...but will be a tremendous help in the future. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @NWHikerOR You're welcome! ) Also re. the possibility of logs deletion - there isn't much you can do about that. AD keeps account creation timestamps as `whenCreated` property but for local accounts it's not implemented.